# Index ANDing and ORing

Tags: sql-server

I have come across the terms index ANDing or ORing while reading BOL. But there seems to be little explanation as to what they actually are.

The following is the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

The paragraph the term appears:

> If  indexes are used in a single hint list, the duplicates are ignored and the rest of the listed indexes are used to retrieve the rows of the table. The order of the indexes in the index hint is significant. A multiple index hint also enforces index **ANDing**, and the query optimizer applies as many conditions as possible on each index accessed. If the collection of hinted indexes do not include all columns referenced by the query, a fetch is performed to retrieve the remaining columns after the SQL Server Database Engine retrieves all the indexed columns.

Can someone explain they they work or give a link for further reading?

Comment: Are you talking about index intersection and index Union plans? Can you provide a link to where these terms are used?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post, and added a link to BOL. Thanks

Comment: Is this just academic? I mean, index hints at all should be used as a last resort, can you show an example where *multiple* index hints against the same table improves performance?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It isn't multiple index hints. It is one index hint with multiple indexes listed. And yes, I am mainly trying to understand the concept, not that I know of any situations where it improves performance.

Comment: @John The syntax is a single hint but you're hinting multiple indexes, yes? That is what I meant. Irrelevant anyway.